# proper way to reference documents with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I see in all examples the suffix "_id" on a field referencing to another document.

Example:

```
record: {
   _id : ObjectId("57f2fb5d1c6c3b0de45b170e",
   artist_id: "prince" )
}

artist: {
   _id: "prince"
}
```

Being that my artist mongo Schema has the "unique" attribute on the name field.

Is it Ok to things like below ?

```
record: {
   _id : ObjectId("57f2fb5d1c6c3b0de45b170e",
   artist: "prince" )
}

artist: {
   _id : ObjectId(6eygdqzd5d1c6c3b0de45b1s0r",
   name: "prince"
}
```

Or should you always reference directly the Id like in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

if you visualize your problem in RDBMS world, there too to establish a foreign key constraint the field should be primary key in the referenced table and the same rule applies here.

now in your artist document though each document is going to contain a unique artist name but the name field itself is not key (primary key) but the ID is.

hence you have to establish the reference using the _id field.

what you can do is for ease if you want rather than relying on the mongodb generated ID field you can probably use name as the _id.